# Construct a mapping of the closed upper half-plane to the closed unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

In my worksheet I have been asked to construct a mapping of the closed upper half-plane to the closed unit disk.

However, I have not been given any definitions, for neither closed upper half-place or the closed unit disk.

Any hints?

Comment: Closed upper half plane:
$$\{z\in\mathbb{C}{\,\colon\,}\text{Im}(z)\ge 0\}$$
Closed unit disk:
$$\{z\in\mathbb{C}{\,\colon\,}|z|\le 1\}$$

Comment: use a Moebius transformation . No matter what you do, a point will be missed (on the boundary), as the closed disc is compact. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation

Comment: @WillJagy: ... unless you consider the closure in the extended complex plane, as it is frequently done in the context of Möbius transformations.

Comment: @MartinR right. I don't expect this OP knows about such things yet.